# PHP Pagination Get Last Page

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

Basically I am trying to get last page... And well it works sometimes but then say some data is entered in then it gets the wrong page and more data is entered then right page will appear I am pretty sure it has something to do with the $r part.
Theres more to it but uh this is the main part. I think I am just using wrong math or functions please help.

```
$limit = 10;
if($_GET['page'] == 0 OR $_GET['page'] == 1) {
    $offset = 0;
} else {
    $offset = $limit * $_GET['page'] - $limit;
}
$next = $_GET['page'] + 1;
$back = $_GET['page'] - 1;

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();

if($count < $limit) {
    $last = 1;
}

$r = $count % $limit;
if($r < 5) {
    $last = ceil($count / $limit);
} else {
    if($r >= 5) {
        $last = floor($count / $limit);
    }
}

if($_GET['page'] == 0 or $_GET['page'] == 1) {
    if (0 >= $last) {
        $page = 0;
    }
    if (1 >= $last) {
        $page = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: no idea what your asking

Comment: say 12 entries are in and last page is 2 it works say 13 are in db last page might be 1. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesnt.

Comment: according to your code thats not possible - so no clue

Answer (score 0):

First, you're using some very confusing code, which is probably why you're confused and stumbling across odd bugs. For example, `0 >= $last` is the same thing as `$last <= 0` and `1 >= $last` is the same thing as `$last <= 1`. So basically your code reads...

```
if ($last <= 0) {
    $page = 0;
}

if ($last <= 1) {
    $page = 1;
}
```

Which if you think about this just means that if `$last <= 1` then `$page` will **always** be `1`. Your conditions aren't *either* — *or*, so both conditions can be met. This hardly makes sense. Especially since `$last` really shouldn't be expected to be anything *other than* 1 or more in any given condition (***i.e. `$page` will always be 1***)

Also, your logic to `floor` or `ceil` `$last` hardly makes sense. You don't actually want to do either or one or the other depending on the value of `$r`. You just always want to `ceil` regardless.

The idea is if you have 10 things or less, and you're placing up to 10 things per page, then you know that you need exactly 1 page. The problem begins when you have 11 things. Now you need 2 pages, because the extra 1 thing still exceeds the limit of 10 per page. So if you really think about this what this means is that the number of pages needed is **always going to be congruent to** `ceil($count / $limit)`. You would **never** floor that number.

Because `ceil(16 / 10) == 2`, but according to your logic you would be doing `floor(16 / 10)` which is actually `1`. But you can't put 16 things on 1 page if the limit per page is 10.